# Peforce command line - How can I replace a depot folder with an existing folder on my desktop (ie. "version-up" depot folder)

Tags: command-line, perforce

I have this depot folder:

> //marketplace/assets/myItem_12345

I have this folder on my desktop:

> C:\Users\myname\Desktop\newVersion

I would like the contents of the depot folder to be replaced with the contents of my desktop folder.

What is the simplest way to do this from the command line?

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal workflow you'd already have a client workspace with a local copy of these files, and you'd just put the new files in the corresponding local folder (instead of on your desktop) and check them in from there.

But, assuming you don't already have a client workspace on this machine:

1. Create a client workspace whose `Root` is `C:\Users\myname\Desktop\newVersion` and whose `View` maps `//marketplace/assets/myItem_12345/...` to the client root.
2. `p4 flush` the workspace so that the server doesn't try to send you the files that are already in the depot (or resolve your local files against them).
3. `p4 reconcile` to reconcile your local files, starting from the assumption (established by `p4 flush` above) that you already got all the latest depot files.
4. `p4 submit`

```
cd C:\Users\myname\Desktop\newVersion
p4 set P4CLIENT=myname_myhost_myItem_12345
p4 --field "View=//marketplace/assets/myItem_12345/... //myname_myhost_myItem_12345/..." client -o | p4 client -i
p4 flush ...
p4 reconcile ...
p4 submit -d "New version of myItem_12345"
```

If this was a one-time operation and you don't anticipate using this workspace ever again, delete it at the end:

```
p4 client -d myname_myhost_myItem_12345
```

Comment: I was trying this solution myself, but I didn't have p4 flush!  Awesome solution, and much appreciated! Thanks so much!